# Different static files in different templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I had stuck in static files.

When I tried to `{% load staticfiles %}` in my main template (e.x. `{% static "main.js" %}`), it works great in main.html template.
 But when I tried to extend main.html template by detail.html template, and put there another static file (e.x. `{% staticfiles 'fancybox.js' %}`), it displays only

`<script type="text/javascript" src="static/main.js"></script>`

instead

`<script type="text/javascript" src="static/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/fancybox.js"></script>`

in my detail.html.

main.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
<!-- SOME CONTENT -->
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

detail.html:

```html
{% extends 'layout/main.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'fancybox.js' %}"></script>

{% block title %}
<!-- SOME CONTENT -->
{% endblock %}
```

Can somebody help me with solution?

Thanks mates.

Comment: Do you have a `{% load staticfiles %}` in `detail.html`?

Comment: @user2896976 Yes, I have.

Comment: Can you post both full templates?

Comment: @user2896976 I've update info above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend a template you need to make sure all of the code in the child template is inside a block. So for your main template typically you do something like:

**main.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- This should go at the top for readability -->

<!-- Load any site wide JS here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>

{% block js %}<!-- Put JS in here for extended templates -->{% endblock %}
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends 'layout/main.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block js %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'fancybox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
<!-- SOME CONTENT -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% extends 'layout/main.html' %}
  {% block title %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'fancybox.js' %}"></script>

  
    <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
    {% endblock %}
```

use this code in details.html.You have to put {% block body%}
at the top just after the extend or include statement